# SIGILL /proc/self/maps: cant execute native codes

Tags: crash

Can somebody help me how to repair this problem ? how to repair a /proc/self/maps path ? bcs i cant start native codes ... When i try open native script i get automatically SIGILL and i dont know why...

```
root@server:/servers/Fivem/server-data# cd /servers/Fivem/server-data && bash /servers/Fivem/run.sh
c-server-monitor]   _______  ______
c-server-monitor]  |  ___\ \/ / ___|  ___ _ ____   _____ _ __
c-server-monitor]  | |_   \  /\___ \ / _ \ '__\ \ / / _ \ '__|
c-server-monitor]  |  _|  /  \ ___) |  __/ |   \ V /  __/ |
c-server-monitor]  |_|   /_/\_\____/ \___|_|    \_/ \___|_|
c-server-monitor] -------------------------------- monitor ---
c-server-monitor]
c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for _cfx_internal
c-scripting-core] Creating script environments for monitor
[txAdmin:v4.18.1] Profile 'default' starting...
[txAdmin:WebServer] Listening on 0.0.0.0.
> /proc/self/maps:
4089f000-408cf000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
40f93000-40fa3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
21800000000-21800003000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
21800003000-21800004000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21800004000-21800014000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
21800014000-2180003f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
2180003f000-21800040000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21800040000-21800043000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
21800043000-21800044000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21800044000-2180007f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
2180007f000-21800080000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21800080000-21800083000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
21800083000-21800084000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21800084000-218000bf000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
218000bf000-218000c0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
218000c0000-218000c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
218000c3000-218000c4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
218000c4000-218000ff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
218000ff000-21808000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21808000000-21808021000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0
21808021000-21808040000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21808040000-218080cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
218080cd000-21808100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
21808100000-21808103000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
21808103000-21808140000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7f40c1696dfb):
0x7f40c1696deb  80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 6f 4c cf f0 f3 0f 6f 14 cf  .......oL....o..
0x7f40c1696dfb  66 0f 38 00 d0 66 0f 38 00 c8 f3 0f 7f 56 d0 f3  f.8..f.8.....V..
0x7f40c1696e0b  0f 7f 4e e0 f3 0f 6f 4c cf d0 f3 0f 6f 54 cf e0  ..N...oL....oT..
0x7f40c1696e1b  66 0f 38 00 d0 66 0f 38 00 c8 f3 0f 7f 56 f0 f3  f.8..f.8.....V..

> =================================================================
Got a SIGILL while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
> =================================================================
```

i tried vm.max_map_count) increased it to 262144 by adding vm.max_map_count=262144 to /etc/sysctl.conf update and upgrade all things what i can'

I tried search error codes like (0x7f40c1696dfb) (( I get only Andorid results))

i tried reinstall my VPS too doesnt help me

i tried after reinstall update my LIB and still... nothing happens

here is DMP file https://we.tl/t-5aoKH8aS7S i dont know what its mean and how to open... anybody can help ?

[image]

Comment: `/proc/self/maps` is no regular file, it's the memory map of the process. You'd have to debug your code to get further info. The 0x7f... is the address where the error is happening btw. SIGILL is "Illegal instruction"

Comment: maybe this will help to us https://we.tl/t-5aoKH8aS7S can you check it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.